# Cannot get Tracking ID for mobile project

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I should get the Tracking Id from Google Analytics to use it in my project, but none of the support pages can really cover my problem.

1. First of all i cannot see the *Tracking information* menu on my dashboard under the Property column - as some setup guide mention it - , I only see the property settings, which from i can navigate to the Firebase console, and the user settings
2. After this I find another support page to get the Tracking Id from the Firebase console (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587086?hl=en) , but this also confuses me. It says "Under the *Data Sharing Settings* section, select the settings you want, and click the **Get Tracking ID** "

In the firebase console settings board I find a *Data privacy* menu with az *Analytics settings* submenu, but still no Tracking ID option.

As I know I need this ID to integrate the Analytics, or is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I found a workaround

Open the https://analytics.google.com page, on the top of the page there is a drop-down.

If you click on that dropdown you can see your Analytics accounts in the first column.

The **number** under your account name **is actually your Tracking base-ID**.

If you have one project for that account, then your Tracking ID could be *UA-123456789-1*

#### One more example

1. Delete your project (place it to the bin)
2. Restore it
3. Check the e-mails you got, there you will find the property which you deleted, and beside the project name there is the Tracking ID